# Class.getResourceAsStream thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Code on a web server:

```
public byte[] loadData() {
    byte[] data = null;
    try(final InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.bin")) { 
        data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(resourceStream); //ByteStreams is from Guava library
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Is there a problem with several threads opening a stream on a resource and reading its content? In this case the resource is a data file contained in a jar.

On windows concurrently reading the resource was not a problem. However this is not efficient so I opted to use a [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and double-checked locking to load the data only once.

Comment: everytinh is ocal to `loadData`, so there should be nop problem!

Comment: @A4L I just wasn't sure about several streams pointing to the same resource on disk being read concurrently!

Comment: you were right - on some operating systems (like windows) your standard method of opening files will create an inherent lock.

Comment: We had this problem on an older JVM, but it took about 4 concurrent threads before it appeared. We added a synchronized (String.intern("resourcepath")) block around the resource load to prevent whatever race state was happening in the class loader.

Comment: This was a problem for us when the resource was loaded from a JAR, but not the file system.  I found some closed bug reports discussing some bad optimizations once one thread had read the InputStream to the end of the contents but not yet closed the InputStream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only state that may *possibly* be shared between your threads is the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream(String)`. Let's check if it's the same object.

Here's a very simple test you can use to try this out yourself:

```
InputStream first = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.bin")
InputStream second = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.bin")
System.out.println(first == second);
```

This will (typically) return `false`. Since they aren't the same object, you have no thread safety issues.

---

I say *typically* because `getResourceAsStream` depends on the underlying `ClassLoader` that loaded the `Class` instance returned by `getClass()`. So, unless you're writing and using your own (or 3rd party) `ClassLoader` objects, you'll be fine.

Comment: This example is not even using multiple threads as posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can access above file via `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`. Reading files is always safe, i.e. not require synchronization.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` as opposed to `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`?

Comment: The first one can be used to load system resources, do you have one?

Comment: @Roland `Class#getResource()` delegates to its `getClassLoader()`.

Answer (score -5):

[No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), multiple threads accessing the same file concurrently **will** throw an exception at some point because without shared read-access your file will be locked everytime you successfuly opened it from any thread, all the other threads will fail until the file is closed again.

You can avoid exceptions with the [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword, that wil enable you to start as many threads as you like without running into problems ever - mind you : since the threads will be forced to execute the function in a sequential manner, your read-performance will drop drastically.

Another possibility would be [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), these classes appear to be threadsafe by design

**edit** : apparently this issue has been resolved a few years ago - but only if you use the "new filesystem API" in java, see the comments for more info

Comment: Except you aren't getting files, you are getting classpath resources.

Comment: um ... thats exactly what it is - unless you pre-load your resources via other means and add them to the classpath ... im guessing that would'nt be easy to accomplish (but of course i could be wrong here)

Comment: And the .NET documentation proves what? Do note that getResourceAsStream() returns an *InputStream*, its impossible to write to it; so even if the resource is a file, it will be opened for shared read. Calling the methode multiple times will yield completely independent streams; no need to synchronize anything.

Comment: well, yet again i have to observe that most people have no clue about how operating systems (especially windows) works. Your ".NET documentation" is actually the WINAPI-documentation - in all of the frameworks the fundamental functionality is identical ... within Windows, that is. Now, before this thread gets troll-deleted away (i know reality is hard to accept for SO-trolls) : would you care to point me to the JVM-documentation in which it is clearly stated that every FileInputStream results in a native, SHARED file-handle, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: and before you ask, here is the lowest-level API-function which is forcibly used by ALL the windows-binaries in existence. Well ... one may use special kernel-functions instead but thats another story and doesnt apply to most developers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Yes, even the JVM uses it. No, there is no "bypass" of this function. Yes, even OpenFile transparently calls this function even though its name would suggest otherwise. Yes, i can prove that but lets not push SO-boundaries here.

Comment: While AFAIK it isn't documented, the JVM does (of course) use FILE_SHARE_READ.  See for example http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6357433

Comment: actually reading all of the comments above would've answered your question.
@Harry Jonhston Well, thank you very much for your clarification - im quite shocked to read that it took sun several years to even implement the most basic functionalities but ... oh well, java is an very abstract language.